# Menu bar in Libreoffice flatpak under Kubuntu 21.10 has no separators

Tags: kde, libreoffice, wayland

After updating to Kubuntu 21.10, libreoffice under wayland looks like this:
[image]

The titles of the menu bar "columns" are not separated. Any ideas how to revert this?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can run the flatpak version of libreoffice with GTK, which is a bit uglier and a lot more stable:

```
SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk3 flatpak run org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/x86_64/stable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, use the apt version of libreoffice, which has the same version 7.2.2.

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

In future,you can use the official PPA to get a later version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice
```